# How to create a three level hierarchical view of relational columns

Tags: google-sheets

I've been struggling creating the following view but I'm so close.

- I have a dataset with three columns of data where each level is broader than the other
- I want to be able to filter the data dynamically by two of the columns
- I want to create a visual where you can see the grouping clearly. I managed to create the two level hierarchy but I'm struggling to get the third.
- As you will see I'm using QUERY in order to use only one formula to power everything

[image]

Here's the formula I'm using for the two level view, but how can I modify it so the output includes the  three levels? Here's the [spreadsheet that you can use as example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_EOj7kBuL5Ujw_OE6q2Po_yXE9TmuT3AHOlXUW91VdY/edit?usp=sharing), with my own function. Appreciate any input!

```
=ArrayFormula({
IF(

QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SORT({SPLIT(UNIQUE(
FILTER(B6:B,B6:B<>"",
IF(F5="",A6:A<>"",B6:B=F5),
IF(F6="",A6:A<>"",C6:C=F6)))&"|#%","|",0,0);

FILTER({B6:B,A6:A},B6:B<>"",
IF(F5="",A6:A<>"",B6:B=F5),
IF(F6="",A6:A<>"",C6:C=F6))},1,1),"#%",""),"Select Col2")="",

QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SORT({SPLIT(UNIQUE(
FILTER(B6:B,B6:B<>"",
IF(F5="",A6:A<>"",B6:B=F5),
IF(F6="",A6:A<>"",C6:C=F6)))&"|#%","|",0,0);

FILTER({B6:B,A6:A},B6:B<>"",
IF(F5="",A6:A<>"",B6:B=F5),
IF(F6="",A6:A<>"",C6:C=F6))},1,1),"#%",""),"Select Col1"),""),

QUERY(
SUBSTITUTE(SORT({SPLIT(UNIQUE(
FILTER(B6:B,B6:B<>"",
IF(F5="",A6:A<>"",B6:B=F5),
IF(F6="",A6:A<>"",C6:C=F6)))&"|#%","|",0,0);

FILTER({B6:B,A6:A},B6:B<>"",
IF(F5="",A6:A<>"",B6:B=F5),
IF(F6="",A6:A<>"",C6:C=F6))},1,1),"#%",""),"Select Col2")})
```

Comment: Try Pivot table (columns L:N in your file) in case using formula isn't strict requirement.

Comment: Almost a duplicate - [How would you create a dynamic visualization with two hierarchical categories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63970449/1330560) on Stack Overflow. Read this post and then comment here if you're still not sure how to proceed,  BTW, is this homework?

Comment: OlegS using a formula is a strict requirement but thank you for the suggestion! @tedinoz I read that post and kind of used their approach, but I need a three level vs the two level they have. It's not homework but I'm helping someone. Would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: @Mel from StackOverflow seems to be using the exact same data as you - quite a co-incidence, don't you think. I wonder whether Mel has any thought on creating a third tier.

Comment: @tedinoz I have different data, but copied the sheet in the other post to illustrate what I need